# How is tetration read in spoken English?

Tags: terminology, tetration

How would one read a [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) operation like $^4 3$ in spoken English?

Meaning, what's the equivalent to reading $3 \times 4$ as "three *times* four" or $3^4$ as "three *to the power of* four" for tetration with a "base" of three and an "exponent" of four?

Comment: I *pronounce* it so that it rhymes with concen*tration*. No idea how to read it though.

Comment: I have never needed to pronounce a tetration, and probably you won't either.

Comment: See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSxnqQ6w0S8&t=33s) (I already skipped to the relevant time stamp).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've certainly never needed it myself, but I have kids who will surely ask if there's anything beyond exponentiation :-)

Comment: One way to read $3^4$ is "the fourth power of three." This may be the inspiration for people saying "the fourth tetration of three."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Wikipedia article on tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) says (without reference) that ${}^n a$ should be read as "the $n$th tetration of $a$." This is also the way it is read in [the YouTube video](https://youtu.be/pSxnqQ6w0S8?t=1m27s) linked to in the comments; this is not merely a case of [citogenesis](https://xkcd.com/978/), as the video was made in 2014 and the Wikipedia article did not contain that line until [early 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tetration&type=revision&diff=697968389&oldid=697197284).